# Python- Regular expression to match" <textarea> </textarea> " and anything between them

Tags: python, regex

If the text was

`<textarea>` **xyz asdf qwr** `</textarea>`

I'm trying to write a regular expression which will help me extract the text in **bold**.

So far I have reached `[(<textarea)][</textarea>)]` which will capture the tags but I haven't been able to actually capture the text in between the two tags.

I also tried `[(<textarea)]+.[</textarea>)]` and even `[[(<textarea)]+.[</textarea>)]` but that too isn't giving the right results.

Can someone please throw some light on this or share some links which will help me reach a solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761

Comment: If you'd like to be taken by Zalgo nevertheless, go with `<textarea>.*?</textarea>` ]:->

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a particular reason that you must use regular expression to parse what seems like HTML?  I wouldn't do it.  See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for the best explanation.

This becomes really simple if you use the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module, which is going to be far better at parsing HTML (especially if it is messy HTML).

```
import bs4

f = open("test.html")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f)

for textarea in soup.find_all('textarea'):
    print textarea.get_text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't parse HTML with regex - parse it with a HTML parser! [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

That being said, if you *must* use a regex::

The square brackets `[]` mean "match any character inside", so `[<(textarea)]` means "match <, (, t, e, x, t, a, r, or )".

You probably want `<textarea>(.*?)</textarea>`, with group 1 (the first set of brackets) being the contents of the tag.

This will have problems (for example) if the user writes `"</textarea>"` inside the text area; then only up to the first occurence of `"</textarea>"` will be extracted. However if you make it non-greedy and do `<textarea>.*</textarea>` then if you have multiple `textarea` tags, the `.*` will match over both of them instead of each individually. Such are the pitfalls of using regex with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were struggling to understand that the "+" and "*" operators refer to the pattern they **follow**, not the pattern they precede.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"\<textarea\>.*\<textarea/\>", target)
>>> re.match(r"\<textarea\>.*\</textarea>", target)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106528b90>
>>> mo = re.match(r"\<textarea\>.*\</textarea>", target)
>>> mo.groups()
()
>>> mo.group(0)
'<textarea> xyz asdf qwr </textarea>'
>>> mo = re.match(r"\<textarea\>(.*)\</textarea>", target)
>>> mo.groups()
(' xyz asdf qwr ',)
>>> mo.group(0)
'<textarea> xyz asdf qwr </textarea>'
>>> mo.group(1)
' xyz asdf qwr '
>>>
```

Does that help?

Comment: Also follow the good advice about a) being wary of greedy matching, and b) considering the use of a suitable HTML parser.